# Why is the first element undefined the second time I iterate through the collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside my function/object I have

```
this.StatusMappings = [
   {
       Range: [Infinity*-1, 50],
       Color: 'red',
       Text: 'Just getting started - will require considerable time to complete.'
   },
   {
       Range: [50, 70],
       Color: 'yellow',
       Text: 'Incomplete - major gaps exist and completion will take some time.'
   },
   {
       Range : [70, 90],
       Color : 'yellgreen',
       Text : 'Partially completed - but some gaps remain which can be completed shortly.'
   },
   {
       Range: [90, Infinity],
       Color: 'green',
       Text: 'Fully completed - no additional work needed.'
   }
];

this.UpdateInfo = function ( $slider, newval )
{
    var color = this.StatusMappings.firstOrUndefined(function (map) {
        console.log("map.Range = "); console.log(map.Range);//TEST
        return map.Range[0] >= newval && map.Range[1] < newval;
    });
    $slider.closest('.slider').addClass(color);
}
```

and what's strange is that the first time `UpdateInfo` is called, everything goes as expected, whereas the second time I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Because of my `//TEST` I see that it works the first time:

[image]

By the way, my helper function `firstOrUndefined` is

```
Array.prototype.firstOrUndefined = function ( unpred )
{
    for ( var i in this ) 
        if ( unpred(this[i]) )
            return this[i];          
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the result of your `for-in` loop. The `for-in` loop accesses properties, methods and array members. My guess is that the this[i] member is probably a property or method of the Array.prototype instance and not an actual StatusMapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When iterating over Arrays in JavaScript, it is never a good idea to use the `for-in` loop. It is always better to use a `for` loop to iterate over the Array. The `for-in` loop in JavaScript does not only access the Array members, it also accesses the Array prototype properties and methods. My testing in JSFiddle reveals that my hypothesis is correct, and the error is resulting from the fact that the `Array.prototype.firstOrUndefined()` extension is being passed into your unpred function, and that function does not have a property of `0`. You can fix this by changing your `for-in` loop to a `for` loop.

```
Array.prototype.firstOrUndefined = function(unpred) {
  //Might be a good idea to validate unpred, too.
  if (typeof unpred === 'function') {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (unpred(this[i]))
           return this[i];
  }
}
```

Please see the fiddle for a reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/7bdj6j92/2/

Further information on the reason why you shouldn't use the `for-in` loop with JavaScript Arrays: [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Beat me to it, was about to post the exact same thing. :)